# Systematically applying multiple filters on data frame

Tags: r

I want to systematically and one by one apply multiple filters on a data frame and get to know how many rows were removed by each filter.

Bonus points if it's possible to return how many rows would have been removed by filter n if non of the filters 1, ..., n-1 had been applied.

My current code as a starting point:

```
my_data <- data.frame(Criterion1 = c(1:9,1:3,3:7,2:4,6:1),
                      Criterion2 = c(9:1,3:1,2:3,1:9,5:3))

my_filters <- data.frame(Filter = c('Criterion1 != 2', 'Criterion2 != 4', 'Criterion1 != 9'),
                         Description = c('Remove all Rows with 2', 'Remove all Rows with 4', 'Remove all Rows with 9'))

lapply(my_filters, function(cur_filter) {
 my_data <- filter(my_data, cur_filter$Filter)
 cat(nrow(my_data), 'rows remaining after applying Filter "', cur_filter$Description, '"') # nicer: printing how many rows have been removed
})
```

(Instead of printing every time with `cat`, I think it would be nice to instead create a table, collect all "removing information" there and print the table at the end.)

I'm open to store my filters other than currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function that takes your data frame and your filter frame, and returns a list of the final data (after all filters applied), and information on what is the effect of either isolated applicaton of the filter or hierachical application of the filter:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(df, filters) {
  static_df = df
  for(i in 1:nrow(filters)) {
    filter = filters[i, "Filter"]
    filters[i,"isolated_n_removed"] <- nrow(static_df) - nrow(filter(static_df, eval(rlang::parse_expr(filter)))) 
    filters[i, "hierarchical_n_removed"] <- nrow(df)-nrow(filter(df, eval(rlang::parse_expr(filter))))
    df = filter(df, eval(rlang::parse_expr(filter)))
  }
  return(list("filtered_data" = df, "filter_effects"=filters))
}
```

Apply the function to your inputs:

```
f(my_data, my_filters)
```

Output:

```
$filtered_data
   Criterion1 Criterion2
1           1          9
2           3          7
3           4          6
4           5          5
5           7          3
6           8          2
7           1          3
8           3          1
9           3          2
10          4          3
11          5          1
12          6          2
13          7          3
14          3          5
15          4          6
16          6          7
17          5          8
18          4          9
19          3          5
20          1          3

$filter_effects
           Filter            Description isolated_n_removed hierarchical_n_removed
1 Criterion1 != 2 Remove all Rows with 2                  4                      4
2 Criterion2 != 4 Remove all Rows with 4                  3                      1
3 Criterion1 != 9 Remove all Rows with 9                  1                      1
```

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of `rlang::parse_expr()`

Comment: The line `desc = filters[i, "Description"]` is not needed :)

Comment: you are right.. I was using it only initially, and then discarded. Will remove

Comment: a nice solution! some side notes, `base::str2expression` can be used as well instead of using `rlang::parse_expr` and perhaps it is more efficient to convert them at once to expressions like `filters$Filter <- str2expression(filters$Filter)` so you only have to evaluate them in your loop.